# Plotly/dash Dashboard is not live updating - Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, live-update

I have written a script which deploys a Dashboard using plotly-dash. It has graphs, data for which is coming from the excel file located on the PC. This data is stored in the excel file which will be updated on a daily basis. What can I do for the app to get updated with the new data without me redeploying it every day? Maybe you can give some advice or ideas?

P.S. The dashboard is currently deployed using Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

If your app reads the file in as part of a callback based on something like the pathname (`dcc.Location`), then you could just refresh the page.